# Erro ao gerar build em modo release android no IONIC -V1

Tags: android, ionic, apache-cordova, build

Quando rodo o comando `ionic cordova build android --release` ele me retorna esse error:

```
Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "fs" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

Já removi e adicionei a plataforma,exclui a pasta node_modules e executei esse comando: `npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev`

E já tentei o `ionic repair`.

Comment: Isso parece ser um problema com algum plugin que você está usando. Tente rodar o comando de build com o parâmetro `--verbose` para ver exatamente de onde vem esse erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mude a versão do seu cordova, a metodos que estão sendo utilizados pelos seus plugins que não são suportados nessa versão do cordova, recomendo fazer o Downgrade

1 - `npm uninstall -g cordova`

2 - `npm cache clean --force`

3 - `npm i -g cordova@8.1.2`

caso não funcione tente outras versões, você pode também pra fim de testes fazer a remoção de plugin por plugin pra ver qual está causando o problema, recomendo remover os plugins utilizando o `--save`